# Conversion of list to string - TCL

Tags: string, list, tcl

I encountered the following problem in TCL. In my application, I read very large text files (some hundreds of MB) into TCl list. The list is then returned by the function to the main context, and then checked for emptiness. Here is the code snapshot:

`set merged_trace_list [merge_trace_files $exclude_trace_file $trace_filenames ]`

`if {$merged_trace_list == ""} {`
`...`

And I get crash at the "if" line. The crash seems to be related to memory overflow. I thought that the comparison to "" forces TCL to convert list to the string, and since the string is too long, this causes crash. I then replaced above "if" line by another one:

`if {[lempty $merged_trace_list]} {`

and crash indeed disappeared. In the light of the above, I have several questions:

1. What is the maximum allowed string length in TCL?
2. What is difference between string and list in TCL in terms of memory allocation? Why I can have very long list, but not corresponding string?
3. When the list first returned by the function into the main scope (the first line) , is it not converted to the string first? And if yes, why I don't have crash in that line?

Thanks,
I hope the descriptions and the questions are clear.

Konstantin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current maximum size of individual memory object (e.g., string) is 2GB. *This is a known bug* (of long standing) on 64-bit platforms, but fixing it requires a significant ABI and API breaking change, so it won't appear until Tcl 9.0.

The difference between strings and lists is that strings are stored in a single block of memory, whereas lists are stored in an array of pointers to elements. You can probably get 256k elements in a list no problem, but after that you might run into problems as the array reaches the 2GB limit.

Tcl's value objects may be *simultaneously both* lists and strings; the dictum about Tcl that “everything is a string” is not actually true, it's just that everything may be serialized to a string. The returning of a list does not force it to be converted to string — that's actually a fairly slow operation — but comparing the value for equality with a string *does* force the generation of the string. The `lempty` command must be instead getting the length of the string (you can use `llength` to do the same thing) and comparing that to zero.

---

Can you adjust your program to not need to hold all that data in memory at once? It's living a little dangerously given the bug mentioned above.

Comment: On the plus side, we've just had a meeting this week that agreed the strategy for starting serious development on Tcl 9.0; we'll get busy with it once we get 8.6.5 released, and that's planned by the start of December this year.

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned some important things on TCL from you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but it's slightly too much for a comment.

If you want to check if a list is empty, the best option is `llength`. If the list length is 0, your list has no content. The low-level lookup for this is very cheap.

If you still want to determine if a list is empty by comparing it to the empty string you will have to face the cost of resolving the string representation of the list. In this case, `$myLongList eq {}` is preferable to `$myLongList == {}`, since the latter comparison also forces the interpreter to check if the operands are numeric (at least it used to be like that, it might have changed).

Comment: I can't remember if we optimize things in the case where we detect that one of the values being compared is known to be  _definitely_ non-numeric at compile time. If you want a list-empty check, look at the value out of `llength`…